# IF statement doesn't allow Select statement to compare the given string

Tags: if-statement, select, plsql

Write a procedure (oracle plsql) to do any one of the following: (a) update the table course and set the fee of the input course name equal to fee of java course. (b) insert a new row for given input course and set the fee lowest of all courses available in the table. Condition is: do (a) if the input course name is already present in the table otherwise do (b) if the input course name is not in the table.

I am providing here the basic details of table:

```
create table course(cid number primary key, cname varchar2(100), duration number, fee number);
insert into course (CID, CNAME, DURATION, FEE)
values (101, 'java', 30, 13000);

insert into course (CID, CNAME, DURATION, FEE)
values (102, 'c', 20, 5000);

insert into course (CID, CNAME, DURATION, FEE)
values (104, 'oracle', 20, 20000);

insert into course (CID, CNAME, DURATION, FEE)
values (105, 'python', 20, 30000);

insert into course (CID, CNAME, DURATION, FEE)
values (106, 'sql', 20, 1000);
```

I tried the below code but i don't know how to compare the given name for each rows in the table inside IF statement. Please take a look in the code and help me.

```
create or replace procedure proc_CourseFeeUpdateTry(coursename in course.cname%type,
                                                    java_fee   out number) is
  n_fee number;
  j_fee number;
begin
    if course.cname = coursename then --i'm getting error here

      select t.fee into j_fee from course t where t.cname = 'java';
      java_fee := j_fee;
      update course t set t.fee = java_fee where t.cname = coursename;
      dbms_output.put_line('new course added');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm || '-' || sqlcode);
      select min(t.fee) into n_fee from course t;
      java_fee := n_fee;
      insert into course values (103, coursename, 40, java_fee);
    end if;
  commit;
end;
```

Comment: A few things will likely prevent you getting the help that you want. 1) Posting pictures of code is not as good as posting the code. Please edit your question to add (well formatted) code 2) You haven't tagged any language, which will limit how many people see your question, 3) It's better to ask a single, precise question and resolve that, than asking several questions at once.

Comment: im really sorry! I am new to this stack overflow and don't know much about posting here. My question is related to oracle plsql.

Comment: Lease review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances you chance for getting a satisfactory answer. In this case, never ever post images. Also include sample data an the expected output of that data, again at text, no images. Describe your problem in terms of waht you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: hi, i modify my question. please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get seems to flow from a major misconception of available table data to procedure. An IF statement has no problem allowing subsequent selects. The problem here is you referenced a table column (course.cname) without having previously select anything from the course table. Just because a table exists does not give access to the data within it, you must select before referencing column values. So before that IF at you need at least a select and since it's a procedure a Select .. into specifically.  
Now a select into makes column values available **if it exist** but if not it throws NO_DATA_FOUND exception. We this fact to avoid that IF entirely. Further there are 2 instances where you use the structure:

```
select data_value into local variable;
output_variable = local_variable;
```

This is not necessary as you can just select directly into the output_variable.
The following contains 2 revisions to your procedure. The 1st leaving your code as is as much as possible. The 2nd revising the code to make use of all the above mentioned. I hope this helps you understand further.  
  
The minimum necessary change requires you to select the course table prior to your IF statement and handle the no_data_found_error.

```
create or replace procedure proc_CourseFeeUpdateTry(coursename in course.cname%type,
                                                    java_fee   out number) is
  n_fee number;
  j_fee number;

  l_course_name   course.cname%type; 
begin
    begin
        select c.cname
          into l_course_name
          from course c
         where c.cname = coursename;
    exception 
    when no_data_found then 
       null; 
    end ; 

    if l_course_name = coursename then  

      select t.fee into j_fee from course t where t.cname = 'java';
      java_fee := j_fee;
      update course t set t.fee = java_fee where t.cname = coursename;
      dbms_output.put_line('course fee updated');       --- course was not added just updted
    else
      dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm || '-' || sqlcode);
      select min(t.fee) into n_fee from course t;
      java_fee := n_fee;
      insert into course values (103, coursename, 40, java_fee);  --- leave message
      dbms_output.put_line('new course added');
    end if;
  commit;
end;
```

The second version uses the above mentions topics and restructures.

```
create or replace procedure proc_CourseFeeUpdateTry(coursename in course.cname%type,
                                                    java_fee   out number) is

  l_cid course.cid%type; 
begin
    select c.cid 
      into l_cid  
      from course c
     where c.cname = coursename; 

    begin  -- inner block to trap java not found 
       -- if we get here then we know that the implied test cource.cname = coursename is true
       select t.fee into java_fee
         from course t where t.cname = 'java';

       update course t set t.fee = java_fee where cid = l_cid;
       dbms_output.put_line( coursename || ' fee updated');
       commit;
    exception 
      when no_data_found then 
         raise_application_error( -20109, 'course name ''java'' is not in course table');
      end ; -- inner block

exception
when no_data_found then
   -- if we get here the we know that the course name does not exist 
   select min(t.fee) into java_fee from course t;
   insert into course values (103, coursename, 40, java_fee);
   commit; 
end;
```

Notice the insert in both procedures. It hard codes id. As a result your procedure is able to add a row exactly 1 time. This is an extremely poor process. Either pass the new id as a parameter (still not good, but better), or redefine the table to auto generate the key. Depending on your version of Oracle look up sequences and insert triggers (prior to 12c) or Identity Columns (12c and later).

Comment: thanks for explaining. but tell me what if the select returns more than one row, do we use cursor then? and how do we compare each value in IF statement then?

Comment: If more than 1 row is returned you could use a cursor, you would have to then put the processing into LOOP ... END LOOP construct. That would process each row individually. However, in this case you should NOT attempt to process multiple rows returned. That would indicate a MAJOR database problem. The Select min() with no other columns returns 1 row - perhaps null. The others select what at least should be a unique. What would you do if JAVA (or any other course name) existed more that once.

Comment: Best process here and always. Handle  only those errors you are to do so (ie you know what to do). For ALL other errors create a log entry and re-raise the error or just ignore it, it will propagate to the calling process.

Comment: if i have duplicate courses, then for selecting fee, i would filter it like coursname=java and courseid=2... that will give me one fee.

Comment: Wrong answer. You have a data problem. You need to fix that. BTW, with the data you presented "coursename='java' and courseid=2" would give NO_DATA_FOUND. But do what you want, experience is a harsh task master, but it will teach.